# Inertia Vue components not updating until relaunch Laravel Sail

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I have created a freesh Laravel 9 project with Sail, installed jetstream and inertia, but if I try to create a new Vue file, it is not updated until I stop Sail and start it again.

Here are the steps

// create Laravel project

curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash

// start sail

sail up

// install Laravel jetstream

sail composer require laravel/jetstream

// install inertia

sail php artisan jetstream:install inertia

sail npm install
sail npm run dev

sail php artisan migrate

// create a Vue component in Pages/Guests/Guest.vue

// create a test route in web.php

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Guests/Guest');
});
```

If I try to do this, sail npm run dev, and refresh the browser, I have a blank page, and a message in the console "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module './Guests/Guest.vue'"

thanks so much

Comment: You need to recompile your assets. https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/workflow

Comment: I know, but doing "sail npm run dev" its not enough, I have to stop sail, and start it again

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Same problem with three fresh installs